# Google Analytics not working on MeteorJS app

Tags: meteor, google-analytics

I m following the instructions on https://github.com/reywood/meteor-iron-router-ga to implement Google Analytics on a MeteorJS web app.

1. Installed iron-router-ga library

```
$ meteor add reywood:iron-router-ga
```

2. Provided a Meteor Settings as required (on Heroku environment variables):

```
{
    "public": {
        "ga": {
            "id": "UA-XXXX-Y"
        }
    }
}
```

3. Found route.js, added following codes:

```
Router.configure({
    trackPageView: true, //https://github.com/reywood/meteor-iron-router-ga
    ...
});

if (Meteor.isClient) {
    Router.plugin('reywood:iron-router-ga');
}
```

But nothing worked. Completely silent on Google Analytics Dashboard.
Any hints on how should I debug this? The goal is to track site visits with the paths/pages visited.

Answer (score 0):

I've never used that package you mention, but the naive approach works pretty well.

Add to the head of your `index.html`:

```
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/google_analytics.js"></script>
```

In `public/js/google_analytics.js`:

```js
(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){(i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)})(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');
ga('create', 'UA-xxxxxxxx-y', 'auto');
ga('require', 'displayfeatures');
ga('send', 'pageview');
```

One question might be whether this still tracks page views when these pages are reached via client-side routing, and I *think* the answer is yes but haven't verified.